# Windows 8 Metro TextBlock animation

Tags: c#, windows, animation, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In my metro app I have a text block that I would to animate to 100% opacity then back 0% opacity when a if statement is true. How would I go about doing this?

I have done a lot looking around but all the animation tutorials are confusing me.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this in C# to animate from 0 to 1:

```
var sb = new Storyboard();
opacityAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
{
    From = 0.0,
    To = 1.0,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)
};
Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityAnimation, textBlock);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnimation, "Opacity");
sb.Children.Add(opacityAnimation);
sb.Begin();
```

You could also define it in XAML:

```
<Storyboard
    x:Name="fadeInStoryboard"
    Storyboard.TargetName="myTextBlock"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
    <DoubleAnimation
        From="0"
        To="1.0"
        Duration="0:0:1.5" />
</Storyboard>
```

-- then start it in code behind:

```
fadeInStoryboard.Begin();
```

Depending your scenario it might be ideal to use visual states and define the Storyboard as a visual state transition.